# display:block not working on option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

UPDATE : I test my code on firefox and everything was alright but on chrome :|

I have two different selecting drop lists . one for Province and another for cities.
I want to let users first select their Province then i show them cities selection list which is only containing cities of selected Province . my idea was to achieve it this way :

**HTML**

```
<select id="Province">
    <option value = "1">Province1</option>
    <option value = "2">Province2</option>
</select>
<select id = "CityList">
    <option value = "1">city1</option>
    <option value = "1">city2</option>
    <option value = "2">city3</option>
</select>
```

cities with value one are inside Province with value one

**jquery**

```
$("#Province").change(function(){
   $("#CityList option").css({'display':'none'});
   var id = "#CityList option[value = " + $("#Province option:selected").val() + "]" ;
   $(id).css({'display':'block'});
})
```

But the problem is none of the options will get visible again :|
And i checked if i'm selecting correct option by changing font color of it

I don't know why display : block is not working on them

Comment: I don't think display block works on items in a list like that. Why don't you just use .show() and .hide() ?

Comment: I used .show() and .hide() just like display:block nothing is shown after hiding options

Comment: @AndyHolmes `.show() and .hide()` are the same as `.css('display', 'block') //etc`. I tried on a jsfiddle and works fine, anyway, you should improve your use of jQuery elements. Check it:  `http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/wj5fK/`

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your logic because there is no cross browser way to do that only with CSS...

Comment: do you have any other idea for cross browser way ?

Comment: I test my code in firefox and everything is fine :| some thing is wrong in chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the options and then selectivly show them, hide and show are better options.

```
$("#Province").change(function(){
   $("#CityList option").hide();
   var id = "#CityList option[value = " + $("#Province option:selected").val() + "]" ;
   $(id).show();
})
```